# Primefaces Datagrid: Dialog not getting updated with selected values

Tags: primefaces

I have an issue with primefaces datagrid.I am trying to update the dialog box with the selected values on click of p:commandLink.
The Dialog doesnt display any values initially but it gets updated with the previously selected values when i refresh the page and click on commandLink.
I am using primefaces-2.2.1 on JBoss 4.3.0.Any help would be appreciated.

```
  <p:column>
     <p:panel header="#{loc.loc_details}" style="text-align:center">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
           <p:graphicImage value="/user/xyz/resources/images/#{loc.loc_details}.jpg"/> 

           <h:outputText value="#{loc.locality}" />
           <h:outputText value="#{loc.city}" />
           <h:outputText value="#{loc.state}" />
           <p:commandLink  update="locDetail,locDetailGrid" oncomplete="locDialog.show()" title="View Detail" border="0" >
               <p:graphicImage value="/user/xyz/resources/images/imagesCA6ETPOM.jpg" />
              <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{loc}" 
                    target="#{tutorialsBean.selectedLocality}" />
           </p:commandLink>
        </h:panelGrid>
     </p:panel>
  </p:column>
```

```
<p:dialog header="Loc Detail" widgetVar="locDialog" modal="true">
  <p:outputPanel id="locDetail" style="text-align:center;" layout="block">



     <h:panelGrid id="locDetailGrid" columns="2" cellpadding="5">
        <h:outputLabel for="loc_details" value="Locality Details :" />
        <h:outputText id="loc_details" value="#{tutorialsBean.selectedLocality.loc_details}" />

        <h:outputLabel for="city" value="City: " />
        <h:outputText id="city" value="#{tutorialsBean.selectedLocality.city}" />

        <h:outputLabel for="state" value="State: " />
        <h:outputText id="state" value="#{tutorialsBean.selectedLocality.state}" />
        <h:outputText styleClass="text_normal" value="First Name" />
        <p:inputText id="fnameText" value="#{tutorialsBean.firstName}" />
        <h:outputText styleClass="text_normal" value="Last Name" />
        <p:inputText id="lnameText" value="#{tutorialsBean.lastName}" />
         <h:outputText styleClass="text_normal" value="Email" />
        <p:inputText id="emailText" value="#{tutorialsBean.email}" />
        <p:commandButton id="searchButton"  
           value="Submit" action="#{tutorialsBean.submitValues}"
           styleClass="button" />

     </h:panelGrid>
  </p:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

in you commandLink add the update and process attributes in your dialog to refresh the information.

like this:

Put the ID in dialog:

```
 <p:dialog header="Loc Detail" id="locDialog" widgetVar="locDialog" modal="true">
```

Put the Update to dialog:

```
<p:commandLink update="locDetail,locDetailGrid" oncomplete="locDialog.show()" title="View Detail" border="0" update="locDialog" process="@this" ajax="true" partialSubmit="true" >
   <p:graphicImage value="/user/xyz/resources/images/imagesCA6ETPOM.jpg" />
      <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{loc}" target="#{tutorialsBean.selectedLocality}" />
</p:commandLink>
```